# how to implement an image and pdf picker in one single upload button in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building a mobile app by using EXPO.Now i am stucked in a img & pdf picker,i can't pick image and pdf in one single function or button. can anyone know any packages that enable pdf & image picker in one function.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use expo document picker to pick multiple file types and images as following:

```
import * as DocumentPicker from 'expo-document-picker';

const picker = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: "*/*",
        multiple: true,
        copyToCacheDirectory: true
});
```

Check the official expo docs [DocumentPicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/)

Comment: By passing type:'*/*' we can pick all types right? But i have issue on that , in my app i want to restrict mime types  only upload image and pdf

Comment: Sadly Expo picker type is only a string not an array of types.

Answer (score 0):

**If you wanna allow your user to select pdf then you can do this**

```
    async function openDocumentPicker() {
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: "*/*",
        copyToCacheDirectory: true,
        multiple: false,
      });
     
      

      console.log(res)
      var lastThree = res.name.substr(res.name.length - 3);
      if(lastThree == 'pdf')
      {

        if(res.type == 'success')
        {
          //Do Something here 
        }
        

      }
      else
      {
        alert('Please select PDF File')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  }
```